# Не работает INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, insert

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Админ-панель</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="add.php">

Название статьи <br>
<input type="text" name="title"><br>
Текст новоист<br>
<textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="text"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить"><br> 
</form>
<?php

include_once ("../includes/config/connect1.php");

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$title = strip_tags(trim($_POST['title']));
$text = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES ('$title, $text') ");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а почему значения в общих кавычках, включая запятую ? вообще никогда не подставляйте значения в текст запроса, используйте привязываемые параметры http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Я изменил и все никак...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YzfVjuk2
http://pastebin.com/jSdfWXYw

Comment: _INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES ('$title', '$text')_

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.mysql.php. Это расширение устарело с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удално с выпуска 7.0.0. Вместо него используйте mysqli или PDO_MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
mysqli_query(" INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES ('".$title."', '".$text."') ");
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в запросе, нужно поправить на:

```
INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES ('$title', '$text')
```

**Но не советую использовать данный вариант, так как тут можно использовать SQL Injection**

---

> Я бы посоветовал вам переписать код с использованием `mysqli` - [документация](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)

**Вариант с подготовкой запроса (Процедурный стиль):**

```
// Подключение к базе данных 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
// Подготавливаемый запрос 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES (?, ?);");
// Собираем запрос 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $title, $text);
// Выполняем запрос 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
// закрываем запрос
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

---

**Вариант с подготовкой запроса (ООП стиль):**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $date_base);

// Подготавливаем запрос
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES (?, ?);"))) {
    // В случаи ошибки
    echo(date("H:i:s(d.m)")." Exit->Error: PREPARE SQL INSERT");
}

/*  Сбор запроса update */
if(!($stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $text))){
    // В случаи ошибки
    echo(date("H:i:s(d.m)")." Exit->Error: SQL Bind Param (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error);
}

/* Выполняем запрос */
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    // В случаи ошибки
    echo(date("H:i:s(d.m)")." Exit->Error: Не удалось выполнить запрос: (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error);

}
/* Закрываем запрос */
$stmt->close();
```

В принципе можно убрать проверки и получиться:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $date_base);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES (?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $title, $text);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

> Пример кода без mysqli не желателен

Поправьте `mysql_query` на данный вариант:

```
 mysql_query(" INSERT INTO blog (title, text) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, всем спасибо кто помогал, благодарю. Ошибку нашел благодаря тому что приписал die(mysql_error()) и понял в чем ошибка.

P.S. Я новичок в php